# ionic framework/bower install ng-cordova

Tags: java, c++, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project to install ng-cordova,  I ran this command

> bower install ngCordova

this shows me

> bower ionic#1.3.1    ENOGIT git not installed or not in the path.

Can anybody pls put me through?

Comment: You need to install the `git` version control system on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

First install the https://msysgit.github.io/ (if not alredy installed). Then set the Git path.

- Search for '**Edit the system environment variables**'.
- Click on '**Environment Variables**'.
- In the '**System variables**' section, scroll down and click on the
  variable '**Path**'.
- Click '**Edit**'.
- Append this text to the end of the '**Variable value**'.

  ```
   `;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`
  ```

[More about this](http://Bower:%20ENOGIT%20Git%20is%20not%20installed%20or%20not%20in%20the%20PATH).